# PHP Simple Loop breaking at a certain number

Tags: php, math, loops, break

I have a loop I want to break after a certain number. So I want display link every 24 records.

```
for ($i=0; $i<=$TotalProductsString; $i+24)
{
    echo "Page link" . $i . "";
}
```

If `$TotalProductsString=52` then it would display the loop 3 times as 24 can only go into 52 around 3 times.

Comment: You need to replace `$i+24` with `$i += 24`. You are not currently changing the counter value with each loop, only doing a computation and discarding the results.

Comment: 3rd argument should be `$i += 24`.

Comment: @Andrew I would have awarded you the answer if you posted it as an answer.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid Thanks! I prefer just using comments for a "one-liner", but I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop should look like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=$TotalProductsString; $i+=24)
{
    echo "Page link " . $i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
for ($i=0; $i<=$TotalProductsString; $i =$i+24)
{
    echo "Page link" . $i . "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [modulo operator](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php) for that:

```
$i = 1;
foreach($rows as $row) {
  // do your row stuff
  if($i % 24 == 0)
    echo "Page link" . $i . "";
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the question is.
Instead of increasing $i by 24 you can also increase by 1 and check if $i meets the number you are looking for.  For example,

```
for ($i=0; $i<=$TotalProductsString; $i++)
{
    // if the remainder is 0 when dividing $i by 24 
    if ($i % 24 == 0) {
         echo "Page link" . $i . "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> have a loop I want to break after a certain number. So I want display
>   link every 24 records.

You wanna break or you wanna display the link for every 24 records or you wanna to make the two things?

> If $TotalProductsString=52 then it would display the loop 3 times as
>   24 can only go into 52 around 3 times.

24 x 3 = 72, so, 24 can only go 2 times if $TotalProductsString is 52.

If you want to display the page for every 24 records, you could simple put this inside of  your "for":

```
if ($i % 24 == 0) {
     echo "Page link" . $i . "";
}
```

and use $i++ instead of use this: $i+24;